# Change Data Capture Event - retrieving values for all fields

Tags: node.js, jsforce, summer-22, grpc

I have been using the Pub/Sub api to subscribe to `/data/OpportunityChangeEvent` that I have setup in the Change Data Control events. I was hoping this would give me a full replacement object that I could swap out in my application.

However this has only given me a partial object with the "SCHEMA" fields all null except for the value changed.

Is there a way to change the proto file or some other setting to return the NEW Object with all of the fields? Because the partial update response that I receive would require me to potentially request the entire object again through the api.

[image: Example Opportunity ChangeEvent ONE FIELD]

Rough prototype code in TypeScript using Pub/Sub process.

```
import PubSubService from "./pubSubService";
import Configuration from "./configuration";

const jsforce = require("jsforce");
const opportunityTopic = "/data/OpportunityChangeEvent";
Configuration.checkConfig();
let client = new jsforce.Connection();
client.initialize({
  instanceUrl: Configuration.getSfInstanceUrl(),
  accessToken: Configuration.getSfAccessToken(),
});
createPubSub();
// subscribe();

async function createPubSub() {
  const pubSubService = new PubSubService(
    Configuration.getPubSubProtoFilePath(),
    Configuration.getPubSubEndpoint(),
    client,
    Configuration.getSfOrgId()
  );
  const oppSchema = await pubSubService.getEventSchema(opportunityTopic);
  // console.log("got schema", oppSchema);
  pubSubService.subscribe(opportunityTopic, oppSchema, 10, (cdcEvent) => {
    const status = cdcEvent.payload.Status__c?.string;
    const header = cdcEvent.payload.ChangeEventHeader;
    console.log("I got an event", cdcEvent);
    console.log(cdcEvent.payload.ChangeEventHeader);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(cdcEvent?.payload?.ChangeEventHeader));
  });
}
```

```
const grpc = require("@grpc/grpc-js");
const protoLoader = require("@grpc/proto-loader");
const fs = require("fs");
const avro = require("avro-js");
const certifi = require("certifi");

class PubSubService {
  client;

  /**
   * Connects to the Pub/Sub API and returns a gRPC client
   * @param {string} protoFilePath
   * @param {string} endpoint
   * @param {SalesforceClient} salesforceClient
   * @param {string} organizationId
   */
  constructor(protoFilePath, endpoint, salesforceClient, organizationId) {
    // Read certificates
    const rootCert = fs.readFileSync(certifi);
    // Load proto definition
    const packageDef = protoLoader.loadSync(protoFilePath, {});
    const grpcObj = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDef);
    const sfdcPackage = grpcObj.eventbus.v1;

    // Prepare gRPC connection
    const metaCallback = (_params, callback) => {
      const meta = new grpc.Metadata();
      meta.add("accesstoken", salesforceClient.accessToken);
      meta.add("instanceurl", salesforceClient.instanceUrl);
      meta.add("tenantid", organizationId);
      callback(null, meta);
    };
    const callCreds =
      grpc.credentials.createFromMetadataGenerator(metaCallback);
    const combCreds = grpc.credentials.combineChannelCredentials(
      grpc.credentials.createSsl(rootCert),
      callCreds
    );

    // Save pub/sub gRPC client
    this.client = new sfdcPackage.PubSub(endpoint, combCreds);
    console.log(`Pub/Sub API client is ready to connect`);
  }

  /**
   * Requests the event schema for a topic
   * @param {string} topicName name of the topic that we're fetching
   * @returns {Object} parsed event schema `{id: string, type: Object}`
   */
  async getEventSchema(topicName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.client.GetTopic({ topicName }, (err, response) => {
        if (err) {
          // Handle error
          reject(err);
        } else {
          // Get the schema information
          const schemaId = response.schemaId;
          this.client.GetSchema({ schemaId }, (error, res) => {
            if (error) {
              // Handle error
              reject(err);
            } else {
              const schemaType = avro.parse(res.schemaJson);
              console.log(`Pub/Sub topic schema loaded: ${topicName}`);
              resolve({
                id: schemaId,
                type: schemaType,
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }

  /**
   * Subscribes to a topic using the gRPC client and an event schema
   * @param {string} topicName name of the topic that we're subscribing to
   * @param {Object} schema event schema associated with the topic
   * @param {string} schema.id
   * @param {Object} schema.type
   * @param {number} numRequested number of incoming events that will be accepted before connection is closed
   * @param {Function} eventHandler
   */
  subscribe(topicName, schema, numRequested, eventHandler) {
    const subscription = this.client.Subscribe();
    // Since this is a stream, you can call the write method multiple times.
    // Only the required data is being passed here, the topic name & the numReqested
    // Once the system has received the events == to numReqested then the stream will end.
    const subscribeRequest = {
      topicName,
      numRequested,
    };
    subscription.write(subscribeRequest);
    console.log(
      `Pub/Sub subscribe request sent for ${subscribeRequest.numRequested} events for topic ${topicName}...`
    );

    // Listen to new events.
    subscription.on("data", (data) => {
      if (data?.events) {
        const latestReplayId = data.latestReplayId.readBigUInt64BE();
        console.log(
          `Received ${data.events.length} events, latest replay ID: ${latestReplayId}`
        );
        const parsedEvents = data.events.map((event) => {
          const replayId = event.replayId.readBigUInt64BE().toString();
          const payload = schema.type.fromBuffer(event.event.payload); // This schema is the same which we retreived earlier in the GetSchema rpc.
          return {
            replayId,
            payload,
          };
        });
        console.log(
          "gRPC event payloads: ",
          JSON.stringify(parsedEvents, null, 2)
        );
        parsedEvents.forEach((event) => eventHandler(event));
      } else {
        // If there are no events then every 270 seconds the system will keep publishing the latestReplayId.
      }
    });
    subscription.on("end", () => {
      console.log("gRPC stream ended");
    });
    subscription.on("error", (err) => {
      // Handle errors
      console.error("gRPC stream error: ", JSON.stringify(err));
    });
    subscription.on("status", (status) => {
      console.log("gRPC stream status: ", status);
    });
  }
}
export default PubSubService;
```

```
// Load  config
require("dotenv").config();

class Configuration {
  static checkConfig() {
    [
      "SALESFORCE_ACCESS_TOKEN",
      "SALESFORCE_ORG_ID",
      "SALESFORCE_INSTANCE_URL",
      "PUB_SUB_ENDPOINT",
      "PROTO_FILE",
    ].forEach((varName) => {
      if (!process.env[varName]) {
        console.error(`ERROR: Missing ${varName} environment variable`);
        process.exit(-1);
      }
    });
  }

  static getPubSubEndpoint() {
    return process.env.PUB_SUB_ENDPOINT;
  }

  static getPubSubProtoFilePath() {
    return process.env.PROTO_FILE;
  }

  static getSfAccessToken() {
    return process.env.SALESFORCE_ACCESS_TOKEN;
  }
  static getSfInstanceUrl() {
    return process.env.SALESFORCE_INSTANCE_URL;
  }

  static getSfOrgId() {
    return process.env.SALESFORCE_ORG_ID;
  }
}

export default Configuration;
```

Comment: Welcome to the SF side of SE! I'm fairly new to CDC - and then not via Pub/Sub. According to [this part](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_event_fields_body.htm) of the documentation RE 'Change Event Messages in Pub/Sub API Clients':

Comment: *"For an updated record, the body includes all record and system fields, even if they’re unchanged or empty. **Unchanged fields have an empty value even if they have a value on the record**....The fields that have changed include fields set to null but if you want to find only the fields that were set to null, check `nulledFields`, after decoding it, in `ChangeEventHeader`."* [Empasis added by me.] Something else I read somewhere in the documentation, which I can no longer find, said something about using Schema ID & Event ID to request the full object. So it seems to me that you can't.

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_event_fields_body.htm) says:

> For an updated record, the body includes only the changed fields. It includes empty fields only if they’re updated to an empty value (null). It also includes the LastModifiedDate system field. The body includes the LastModifiedById field only if it has changed—if the user who modified the record is different than the previous user who saved it.

This is a replication API, so it only returns the changes that are relevant. You do indeed need to either store a copy of the data or query the full record from Salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you.
It allows to add a set of fields to every CDC.
[Enrich Change Events with Extra Fields When Subscribed with CometD or Pub/Sub API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_enrich_intro.htm)